# Correct mro order attrs object can't find abstract property

Tags: python, method-resolution-order, python-attrs

The following runs fine:

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
import attr

class A(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def prop(self):
        pass

    def foo(self):
        print(self.prop())

class B:
    def prop(self):
        return 5

class C(B, A):
    pass

C()
```

Here, `C` has a function `prop` inherited from `B` which is found first in the MRO order so `A` wouldn't complain about its existence. I tried this with a `dataclass` as well:

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
from dataclasses import dataclass, field

class A(ABC):
    @property
    @abstractmethod
    def prop(self):
        pass

    def foo(self):
        print(self.prop())

@dataclass
class B:
    prop: int = field(default=5)

class C(B, A):
    pass

C()
```

However, this doesn't work with `attr`:

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
import attr

@attr.s
class A(ABC):
    @property
    @abstractmethod
    def prop(self):
        pass

    def foo(self):
        print(self.prop())

@attr.s
class B:
    prop: int = attr.ib(default=5)

@attr.s
class C(B, A):
    pass

C()
```

Running it:

```
❯ python test.py                                                                                  
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_mro_abstract_property.py", line 22, in <module>
    C()
TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class C with abstract methods prop
```

The codebase I'm working in has standardized on using `attr` so I would like to continue using `attr` if possible. What does `attrs` do differently from `dataclass` such that it can't discover the `prop` member? Are there workarounds for this issue?

The attr version I'm using is 22.1.0 (latest release)

Answer (score 1):

There's a workaround, but I'm not 100% why it works: make B slotted:

```py
@attr.s(slots=True)
class B:
    prop: int = attr.ib(default=5)
```

makes it work.

I suspect it's because abc checks `__slots__` and it's there.

Dataclasses put *some* defaults as class variables on the class body, but not all.

For instance this fails:

```py
@dataclass
class B:
    prop: list = field(default_factory=list)
```

This kind of inconsistencies is why I'm not a fan of treating certain defaults in special ways.

---

JFTR, in modern attrs (20.1.0 from August 2020) your code would look like this (and work, because slots are on by default):

```py
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
import attr

@attr.define
class A(ABC):
    @property
    @abstractmethod
    def prop(self):
        pass

    def foo(self):
        print(self.prop())

@attr.define
class B:
    prop: int = attr.field(default=5)

@attr.define
class C(B, A):
    pass

C()
```

(if you're OK with requiring 21.3, you can even use [`import attrs`](https://hynek.me/articles/import-attrs/))